# how do i get rid of "be the first of your friend to like this"?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I would like a "like" button on each of my webpages. Im using the XFBML code to do this. However I would just like the "like" button and no text, such as the "be the first.." or "You and 10 others like this..". Is it possible to just have the like button and nothing else?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Facebook Button Like page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and configure it your own way.

for example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to just have the like button with no count or text?

Answer (score 1):

OLD question, but for anyone wanting to know, there is a solution, starting with @balexandre's answer:

> Go to the [Facebook Button Like page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and configure it your own
>   way.
>
> for example:
>
> [image]

**THEN,** wrap the div in any object, like this:

```
<div class="my-fb-btn-wrap">
  <!-- Facebook Button Code Here -->
</div>
```

Style the div with the following css styles:

```
.my-fb-btn-wrap {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: 52px;
}
```

You can (and probably need to) play with the styles a bit to match your needs, but you'll need the `overflow:hidden` and `width to` hide the extra text, and `display:block` to get past a cute Chrome bug if the wrapper is usually some other display type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow code.

```
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="{YOUR URL}" data-send="false" 
data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Cheers!

Prasad.